# Oracle NUMBER(precision,scale) in HSQLDB

Tags: java, oracle, numbers, hsqldb, numeric

In a unit test I am trying to generate a table in an in-mem HSQLDB, the table contains a column with the definition: `@Column(name = "xxx", columnDefinition="NUMBER(10,0) default 0")`. NUMBER is not recognized by HSQLDB (version 2.3.3), so I have added a script running this statement first: `CREATE TYPE NUMBER AS NUMERIC;`. Now it seems to recognize NUMBER, but I get the error `unexpected token: (` instead. I cannot edit the column definition, so wow do I correctly map Oracle `NUMBER(10,0)` to `NUMERIC`? If I remove the precision and scale from NUMBER it seems to work.

Comment: `NUMBER(10,0)` would map to `integer`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to define the NUMBER type, as it is supported by HSQLDB.

HSQLDB supports Oracle syntax in one of its compatibility modes. Run this statement to enable it:

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE
```